# Why Doesn't FDT's Launcher Chain Execute Files In The Order I Specified

Tags: compilation, fdt, launching-application

Given the launcher chain below, why do I see the ADT call (which is part of launcher FDT2815)  executed AFTER my task 'AntTask build.xml'?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Any launch or start associated with a launch configuration is always pushed to the end of the chain.

If it's an Ant task (file), they will be executed in order.

The compile part of each launcher will be executed in order, but the launcher is pushed to the end. You can try to use [fdt.invoke.launchConfiguration](http://fdt.powerflasher.com/docs/FDT_Ant_Tasks#fdt.invoke.launchConfiguration_.28FDT_5.5.29)(FDT 5.5) but this may not work in some instances.

In which case `fdt.invoke.launchConfiguration` won't work, [wail till FDT 5.6](http://bugs.powerflasher.com/jira/browse/FDT-2812) (out shortly) which will solve this issue by providing a "Don't launch option" with launchers.

See screenshots below:
[image]
[image]